# clojure set of maps - basic filtering

Tags: clojure

Clojure beginner here..

If I have a set of maps, such as

```
 (def kids #{{:name "Noah" :age 5}
     {:name "George":age 3}
     {:name "Reagan" :age 1.5}})
```

I know I can get names like this

```
  (map :name kids)
```

1) How do I select a specific map? For example
  I want to get back the map where name="Reagan".

```
 {:name "Reagan" :age 1.5}
```

Can this be done using a filter?

2) How about returning the name where age = 3?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can do it with `filter`:

```
(filter #(= (:name %) "Reagan") kids)

(filter #(= (:age %) 3) kids)
```

Answer (score 6):

There's `clojure.set/select`:

```
(clojure.set/select set-of-maps #(-> % :age (= 3)))
```

And similarly with `name` and `"Reagan"`. The return value in this case will be a set.

You could also use `filter` without any special preparations, since `filter` calls `seq` on its collection argument *(edit: as already described by ffriend while I was typing this)*:

```
(filter #(-> % :age (= 3))) set-of-maps)
```

Here the return value will be a lazy seq.

If you know there will only be one item satisfying your predicate in the set, `some` will be more efficient (as it will not process any additional elements after finding the match):

```
(some #(if (-> % :age (= 3)) %) set-of-maps)
```

The return value here will be the matching element.

Comment: Thanks to lazy seqs you can also do `(first (filter …` efficiently.

Comment: True, I guess I mostly prefer it as the more self-documenting option (to my eye, anyway). `some` still has an edge for expensive predicates though (due to chunking).