# How to get a value from a list of maps in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I have a list of maps from which I want to retrieve the value of "field" given a certain "columnId".

```
(def field-to-column-mapping
   [{"field" "first_name", "columnId" "1"}
    {"field" "last_name", "columnId" "2"}
    {"field" "phone", "columnId" "3"}])


(defn get-field-given-column [id]
  ((some #(if (= id (get % "columnId")) %)
         field-to-column-mapping)
   "field"))

 ;; Gets "first_name"
 (get-field-given-column "1")
```

This works, but my gut tells me there has to be a cleaner way to do it.

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [clojure set of maps - basic filtering](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12021312/clojure-set-of-maps-basic-filtering)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are doing lots of look-ups without changing `field-to-column-mapping`, it might be worth constructing a `"columnId" -> "field"` map, e.g.

```
(def column-to-field
   (zipmap
     (map #(% "columnId") field-to-column-mapping)
     (map #(% "field") field-to-column-mapping)))
; {"3" "phone", "2" "last_name", "1" "first_name"}
```

Another way to define `column-to-field` would be (I'm not sure which way is better/more efficient):

```
(def column-to-field
   (apply hash-map
      (mapcat
         #(vector (% "columnId") (% "field"))
         field-to-column-mapping)))
```

Now `(column-to-field "1")` gives the desired result.

Comment: In clojure maps _are functions_ of their keys. So when a lookup function is necessary build a map and use it directly. Very nice!

Answer (score 5):

Writing this using a `for` makes it perhaps a bit clearer while doing essentially
the same thing as the example in your question:

```
(defn get-field-given-column [id] 
   (for [row field-to-column-mapping :when (= (row "columnId") id)] 
      (row "field")))

> (get-field-given-column "1")
("first_name")
```

This returns a sequence of answers, as it is possible for more than one row to have the same key. If there really will only be one, then add a call to `first`.