# How to get specific data from a set that holds hashmaps in clojure by specifying keyword and value

Tags: clojure

How can I find the name "olle" by specifying :id and value of :id in

```
(def persons #{{:id 1 :name "olle"} 
               {:id 2 :name "anna"}})
```

I need to some function that would get the rows that match to be able to access the values and the keys.

I'm trying to implement SQL syntax in clojure, this is for a school assignment, so I don't need code, more like hints on how I should go about it. So far I know that the functions `get-in` and `clojure.set/select` could be used.

Ultimately, what I'm trying to achieve is this statement to be parsed and interpreted

```
select [name]
from persons
where id=1

->"olle"
```

This is what I've been testing with so far with no result

```
    (persons :id 1 :name) 
    ;=> :name "olle"
    => (clojure.set/select :id #{1})
    #{}
    => (clojure.set/select odd? #{1})
    #{1}
```

I've also played around with get-in, but still I have not managed to get the feel of moving around in the set and hash-maps within the set, so much that I can carry on with the coding, also I'm not sure if I need to define any grammar looking code in this assignment or if I can just do with writing algorithms?

Comment: Your are lucky that your school is teaching Clojure!

Comment: See `clojure.set/select`.

Comment: If my edits are to drastic, you can roll them back. Just trying to help.

Answer (score 1):

First off, each definition is not a `list`, they are each a `set` where each element is a `hash-map`. Since this is an assignment, I won't provide the complete code, but I will say that your answer could make good use of [group-by](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/group-by), [get-in](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/get-in), and [update-in](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/update-in).

Comment: The assignment is to implement a SQL syntax like in clojure, these are the only the tabels, could you please give me a hint on how I would use get-in I have tried different things with get-in but beeing a noob I lack a lot of knowledge about the mecanics of this language. 
I'm not sure if I can use get-in because I need to get something like this at the end

select[:id] from table1 where name="john"

Comment: Narrow down your question and show some research effort if you want help. If your question is, "How do implement SQL syntax in Clojure?", it should be voted closed as too broad.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

```
(clojure.set/select #(= 1 (:id %)) persons)
;=> #{{:name "olle", :id 1}}
(clojure.set/project *1 [:name])
;=> #{{:name "olle"}}
```

Presumably your assignment is asking you to come up with a macro transformation from a SQL-like DSL. So, you have two parts to figure out - First, how do I do this with normal functions? Second, how do I effect the transformation with macros?

Comment: Thanks, yes exactly, the assignment says that below "rules" should be parsed and return the value, 

`(select [columns]

from #{table}

where :cell-name (= | in | > | < | != | like value)

orderby :cell-name)`


I also found some good answers here:
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12021312/clojure-set-of-maps-basic-filtering)

thanks

Comment: The `select [columns] from #{table}` bit is equivalent to `(clojure.set/project #{table} [columns])` and the `where` clauses can be implemented with the help of `clojure.set/select` as hinted. So, first make sure you can do all the options with functions, then attempt the macro transformation. Your assignment is probably more about the macro, but you must understand the code you transform to first.

Comment: I'm really struggling with this, how am I supposed to define select from where orderby, is the right way to go symbols?